# Adding Multiple Layouts Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

**Question:** How to add multiple Relative Layouts to an existing Relative Layout.

Please forgive my ignorance as I am still in the process of self learning android dev and there are still a few gaps in my understanding.

My goal is to take this screen: [Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYxAD.png) and Add multiple smaller Relative Layouts to a Linear Layout, in this case that layout is titled rootWorkingLayout. Now currently, my code successfully adds one of the smaller Relative Layouts as seen here: [Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9WhR.png).

My seemingly elusive goal is to have 4 or 5 of these on the screen each with different data within the TextViews (But that's the next step. for me) I am unsure of how to accomplish this.

Main Activity Java Class:

```
public class rootActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar; //Toolbar Declaration
public LinearLayout rootWorkingLayout;
public  static int i = 100; //previewCounter
//Main Function
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);
    toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    rootWorkingLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootWorkingLayout);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Bundle previewReceiver = getIntent().getExtras();
    //If There is a Bundle, Process it
    if(previewReceiver != null) {
        newPreview(previewReceiver);
    }
}
//Create Options Menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
//Track Options Menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_newReport: return true;
        case R.id.action_history: return true;
        case R.id.action_settings: return true;
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
//Launch New Report Wizard
public void newReport (MenuItem menuItem)
{
    Intent startNewReport = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), reportGeneratorActivity.class);
    startActivity(startNewReport);//Go To Report Wizard
}
//Process New Preview
public void newPreview (Bundle previewReceiver) {
    //Extract Strings from Bundle
    String date = previewReceiver.getString("date");
    String client = previewReceiver.getString("client");
    String machine =previewReceiver.getString("machine");
    String serialNum = previewReceiver.getString("serial");
    //Create New Inflater
    LayoutInflater previewInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View previewLayout = previewInflater.inflate(R.layout.previewplate, null);
    //Set Params
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams previewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    previewLayout.setLayoutParams(previewParams);// Add Params to Preview Plate
    //Add previewLayout to rootWorkingLayout
    previewLayout.setId(i);
    //previewLayout.setID(i);//Assing new ID
    i += 100;//Increment ID
    rootWorkingLayout.addView(previewLayout);
    //TODO: Configure Preview Plate
}
```

}

Here is the Main Activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gdt.user.testgdt.rootActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
    android:id="@+id/rootWorkingLayout"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the Layout of the Relative Layout I am attempting to add multiple times to the rootWorkingLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/previewReportPlate"
android:background="#D1D1D1"
android:layout_below="@+id/previewReportPlateLbl"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="Client Name"
android:id="@+id/clientNamePlate"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Machine Type"
android:id="@+id/machineTypePlate"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/clientNamePlate"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Serial Number"
android:id="@+id/serialNumberPlate"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/machineTypePlate" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:text="Date"
android:id="@+id/datePlate"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="691dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/serialNumberPlate"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My current thoughts are that this is an issue with the previewLayout.setId or a rule that I need to declare somewhere. Likely I belive I need to construct some sort of loop eventually that goes through the process. But at this time I think I need help figuring out how to add multiple previewPlate layouts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to set an id to a view before you add it. Generally, the only reason a view needs an id is so you can later find it using `findViewById`.

Comment: My next step after I solve this issue is to begin affecting the text inside the individually added layouts, hence why I was attempting to set an id for each, but I believe I am doing it incorrectly.

Comment: I think the "proper" way to do what you want is with a ListView instead of LinearLayout and an ArrayAdapter to load views dynamically.

Comment: I had considered a ListView, but I lack almost any understanding of it's function in regards to using it to add previewPlates.

Comment: Just look up documentation about custom ArrayAdapters. Each item is a previewplate

Comment: Could you give a brief example of how it would look? If  its not to mich to ask, I tend to learn things faster with code I can trace. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like [this tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now currently, my code successfully adds one of the smaller Relative Layouts

Sure, that is because you only call your method once in `onCreate`.

```
newPreview(previewReceiver);
```

You could copy that line multiple times, and you will see more than one layout.

> My seemingly elusive goal is to have 4 or 5 of these on the screen each with different data within the TextViews

You will need different Bundles each time you call your method to set different data, but all you need to do is call that method again.

And if you are trying to do it with that plus button in the Toolbar, you can do it like so

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_newReport: 
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            // TODO: set some data in the bundle
            newPreview(b);
            return true;
```

Comment: I think I am following so far. The event that triggers the newPreview function comes from another activity as I understand it. In the other activity I have a button, when pressed it creates an intent, creates a bundle, attaches it to the intent then sends it back to the Main Activity where the new layout is added. Pressing the plus button in the toolbar takes the user to the other activity where they can repeat the process and ideally, add another layout with different information as my goal is to allow the user to have different preview plates for each use.

Comment: Okay, so your Intent comes from another Activity, but `onCreate` (and therefore your method) is only called once, so I am not sure how you want to handle that

Comment: Hmm, so if I am understanding, I need to either have some sort of listener set up separately within the Main Activity to trigger newPreview or I have to trigger the method from the other activity correct?